# average and mode with group by

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below:

```
df <- data.frame(code=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),idp=c(120,140),
p_origin=c("yes","yes","no","yes","yes"),returnee=c("yes","no"))
```

I want to take average of idp group by code and mode of p_origin which is "yes" here and mode of returnee
that is if yes is the mode yes should be in column and if no is the mode "no" should be in column if they have equal number of yes and no the "no_sense" should be in column what I want is as below

```
output <- data.frame(code=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),idp=c(120,140),
p_origin=c("yes","yes","no","yes","yes"),returnee=c("yes","no"),
 average_idp=130, Most_frquent_origin="yes",Most_frequent_returnee="no_sense")
```

I am doing to take average of as below

```
iset_df <- iset_df %>% group_by(code) %>% 
            mutate(averag_idp=mean(idp)) %>% 
            mutate(most_frequent_origin=mode(p_origin)
```

Average is perfect but for mode it shows `"numeric"`.

Comment: `mode` is not a statistic mode, it's the *"type or storage mode of an object"* (from `help('mode')`). For the statistic mode, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode).

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you I got that but my problem is like if same number of yes and no how mutate and new column which says "no sense"

Comment: OK, reopened...

Comment: @RuiBarradas can you please help me like a column as below have same number of different values like
```

Comment: Done, see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using function [Modes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/8245406) in the accepted answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode):

```
f <- function(x){
  m <- Modes(x)
  if(length(m) > 1) "no sense" else m
}

df %>% 
  group_by(code) %>% 
  mutate(averag_idp = mean(idp), 
         most_frequent_origin = Modes(p_origin),
         most_frequent_returnee = f(returnee))
```

Comment: @MaxMiak Glad to help. Note that in the `mutate` there is a call to `Modes` and another to the auxiliary function `f`. This could be changed to 2 calls to `f`.